# Update a new high score with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am relatively new to programming with PHP.

I have created a simple Javascript game and I have managed to insert the player's current score into the database. I have two fields, current score and highest score for the player. How do I check if the player's current score is higher than his highest score and update the highest score?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An update statement setting the current score and possibly updating the highest score per user:

```
UPDATE `scores` SET `current_score` = ?, `high_score` = GREATEST(`high_score`, ?)
WHERE `user` = ....
```

Substitute `?` for the score.

Comment: Thank you! I shall test it out with this piece of code. Finally, I have something to proceed with!

Answer (score 1):

After inserting the current score you could run the following query:

```
UPDATE scores
SET high_score = current_score
WHERE current_score > high_score
```

Comment: Thank you! I shall test it out with this piece of code. Finally, I have something to proceed with!